# How to average a row over three columns

Tags: r

Im sure this is simple but Im new to R (like 30 minutes new) and still scratching my head.

I have five columns. I would like to sort the data by a composite of column a and b (a is chromosome, b is locus) and then average the values over columns sample1,sample2 and sample3 to provide a text output.

So far I have the following but I think my means calculation is letting me down

```
#Import the data as a data frame
df = read.table("mydata.txt")

#Make sure its there
summary(df)

#Make sure data is sorted by chromosome and by locus.

df = df[order(df[[1]], df[[2]]), ]
#Take the control samples and average each row for three columns excluding the first two     columns- add the per row means to the data frame

dfmns <- rowMeans( df[ , c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3")] )
```

The sample data is as follows:

```
chr leftPos strand  JWA JWB JWC JWD OE33_F
chr1    100202137   +   2   0   1   0   0
chr1    100260304   -   141 62  75  55  20
chr1    100724039   -   0   1   0   0   0
```

I would like

```
chr      leftPos    strand  JWA JWB JWC JWD OE33_F   Means
chr1    100202137   +          2    0   1   0   0     0.6
chr1    100260304   -        141    62  75  55  20    70.6
chr1    100724039   -          0    1   0   0   0     0.2
```

I think the code falls over at the order function as perhaps Im not referencing the columns properly?

Comment: What makes you think the calculation is wrong? We don't have the input data so we have no idea what those code is retuning or what you expect.

Comment: To get better help from us (as @MrFlick started to say), please read about making a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), including giving us a representative dataset and output that indicates what you want and what you are instead getting.

Comment: chr leftPos strand JWA JWB JWC JWD OE33_F
chr1 100202137 + 2 0 1 0 0
chr1 100260304 - 141 62 75 55 20
chr1 100724039 - 0 1 0 0 0

Comment: The first 3 samples are JWA JWB JWC yes? How do you get a mean of 2 from c(2,0,1)?

Comment: @user3632206.  Your example and code you posted are different.  It is not clear which of the columns are "sample1:sample3".  I tried with a combination of the columns, but was not able to get the "Means" output.

Comment: JeremyS- Apologies I had just put data in to show the format- the means were incorrect but I have now corrected them

Comment: akrun- Yes I think Im not sure how to refer to the columns. The columns I want to get a mean of are JWA JWB JWC JWD and OE33_F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible that you have used some of the `character` columns also into calculating `rowMeans`.  In your example, if you wanted to remove the character columns/not-to-be-selected columns (here they are in positions 1,2, and 3)

```
df$Means <- rowMeans(df[,-(1:3)]) #1:3 refers to the columns `chr` to `strand`
 df
#   chr   leftPos strand JWA JWB JWC JWD OE33_F Means
#1 chr1 100202137      +   2   0   1   0      0   0.6
#2 chr1 100260304      - 141  62  75  55     20  70.6
#3 chr1 100724039      -   0   1   0   0      0   0.2
```

If you have only limited number of columns to perform the mean:

```
rowMeans(df[,c("JWA", "JWB", "JWC","JWD", "OE33_F")])
#[1]  0.6 70.6  0.2
```

Or

```
rowMeans(df[grep("^JW|^OE", colnames(df))])
#[1]  0.6 70.6  0.2
```

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I wanted. Thank you

Comment: What if I want to specify which columns to perform the mean on?

Comment: @user3632206.  How many columns do you want to perform the mean in your actual dataset?

Comment: OK I think I figured it out, I just specify the column index that I want to run the means on eg to get the mean of column 4 and 5 it would be     df$Means <- rowMeans(df[,(4:5)]). Not sure what the syntax would be if I want to get the mean of columns 4 and 6 only though

Comment: rowMeans(df[,c(4,6)])